# Adding numbers in a consecutive series

Tags: permutations

I have the series: 1, 13, 133, 1333 ...

Currently I have distributed it down to: 1 + (10 * 2) + (100 * 2) ... Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Sorry, I forgot to mention, I'm looking for the sum of the series up to n where n is the stage.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

If you multiply all numbers by $3$, you have $$3,39,399,3999,\cdots$$ that is to say $$4-1,40-1,400-1,4000-1,\cdots $$ which look like ... something I let you.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: Hello Claude, I am sorry but I am still not following how this can get the sum of the series.

Comment: Just use the suggested formula for $$a_n=\frac{1}{3} (4\times 10^n - 1)= \frac{4}{3} \times 10^n - \frac{4}{3}$$ and sum from $n=0$ to $n=p$. The first part is a geometric progression and the second part looks quite simple.

Comment: Sorry Again, I have found the pattern doesn't seem to work on stage 0. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the typo $a_n=\frac{4}{3} \times 10^n - \frac{1}{3}$ and this works for $n=0$

Comment: That then equals 1? shouldnt it equal 0?